# How can I parse this paragraph from a textfile using Python

Tags: python

I have a textfile which contains the following:

```
DATE: December 9, 1996

TO: Harold M. Williams

FROM: Greg Phils

SUBJECT: Letter of Annoucement

This email is a reminder to RSVP for the wedding blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah served. 

On October 1, 1990, blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah please.
```

I have been able to use regex to get the date, to, from, and subject with the following code:

```
date = []

for line in lines:
    
     if re.match("(DATE:)", line):
        line.strip()
        date.append(line)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(date))

df3.columns = ['Date of Notice']

df3['Date of Notice'] = df3['Date of Notice'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('DATE:').rstrip('\n'))

df3['Date of Notice'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Date of Notice'])
```

I would like to write a piece of code that would like me parse from "This" to "served." and from "On" to "please"

Comment: Will the files always be formatted in that way?

Comment: @swagless_monk, yes

Comment: Since the files will always be formatted that way, you can just create a list that contains each line of the file and select the specific line you need.

Comment: The output was incorrect before, sorry. The updated version above contains multiple lines which I would like to parse from "This...served"

Answer (score 0):

```py
from glob import glob
import re
import pandas as pd

REGEX_HEADER = re.compile(r"(\w+):\s*([^$]+)")

file_contents = [open(f).read().splitlines() for f in glob("*.txt")]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["DATE", "TO", "FROM", "SUBJECT", "RSVP_INFO", "PROPOSAL"])

for lines in file_contents:
    stuff = {}
    rsvp_info = []
    proposal = []

    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            m = re.match(REGEX_HEADER, line)
            if m is not None:
                stuff[m.group(1)] = m.group(2)
            else:
                if line.startswith("This"):
                    rsvp_info.append(line)
                if line.endswith("served."):
                    if not rsvp_info[-1].endswith("served."):
                        rsvp_info.append(line)
                    stuff["RSVP_INFO"] = "\n".join(rsvp_info)
                    continue
                if line.startswith("This"):
                    continue

                if line.startswith("On"):
                    proposal.append(line)
                if line.endswith("please."):
                    if not proposal[-1].endswith("please."):
                        proposal.append(line)
                    stuff["PROPOSAL"] = "\n".join(proposal)
                    continue
                if line.startswith("On"):
                    continue

                if rsvp_info and not rsvp_info[-1].endswith("served."):
                    rsvp_info.append(line)
                elif proposal and not proposal[-1].endswith("please."):
                    proposal.append(line)
                else:
                    raise RuntimeError(line)
    df = df.append(stuff, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Inputs:

```
DATE: December 9, 1996

TO: Person A

FROM: Person B

SUBJECT: Subject 1

This
email blah
served.

On October 1, 1990,
blah please
```

```
DATE: January 3, 1998

TO: Person C

FROM: Person D

SUBJECT: Subject 2

This blah
blah served.

On February 10, 1960, blah please.
```

Output:

```
               DATE        TO      FROM    SUBJECT                  RSVP_INFO                            PROPOSAL
0  December 9, 1996  Person A  Person B  Subject 1  This\nemail blah\nserved.   On October 1, 1990,\nblah please.
1   January 3, 1998  Person C  Person D  Subject 2    This blah\nblah served.  On February 10, 1960, blah please.
```

Comment: I should have been more specific sorry. I have many text files that are in the same format, and my goal is to parse them into a dataframe. At the moment, i have four dataframes: date, from, subject, and to which have been concatenated into one dataframe. I want to create two new dataframes: rsvp_info, proposal_story. I want to the text "This....served" to be parsed into the rsvp_info dataframe and "On...please" to be parsed into the proposal_story dataframe.

Comment: @curatives_support I have edited the answer. The solution is not exactly what you said you wanted but I think it makes more sense to parse each file into a `dict` and then append that as a row to one single `DataFrame` containing data from all the files. In any case I think you should be able to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much. Going to take a stab at it now.

Comment: I'm still unable to parse multiple lines as from "This" to "served." includes three lines. Could there be an error on my part?

Comment: @curatives_support sorry I didn't see the edit and was assuming that "This" and "served." are supposed to be on 1 line. I'll take another look and try to figure out how do parse multiple lines.

Comment: @curatives_support I have updated the answer, please check. The solution could certainly be made prettier and more efficient but it should work.

Comment: Thank you. Will take a stab.

Comment: it's working. you're an incredible thank you @Czaporka

Comment: @curatives_support Thanks :D In this case please upvote/accept the answer.